# Composition of Morphisms where C is a category

Tags: category-theory

The following is Exercise 3.1 from Aluffi's *Algebra: Chapter Zero*:

> Let $C$ be a category.  Consider a structure $C^{(op)}$ with
>   $\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}$
>
> - $Obj(C^{(op)}):= Obj(C)$
> - for $A, B$ objects of $C^{(op)}$ (hence objects of $C$), $\Hom_{C^{(op)}} (A,B):= \Hom_C (B,A)$.
>
> Show how to make this into a category (that is, define composition of morphisms in $C^{(op)}$ and verify the properties.

Comment: Do you mean to define the *opposite category?*  In that case, you have a critical typo.  The definition of the Hom-sets should read:  $\operatorname{Hom}_{C^{(op)}}(A, B) = \operatorname{Hom}_C(B, A)$.

Comment: No. Its a problem I am working on from the Aluffi's Chapter Zero book

Comment: @Sammy, Drama: I looked it up in [Algebra Chapter Zero](http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~jarekw/pdf/Algebra0TextboookAluffi.pdf). It's Exc.3.1 and is _definitely_ about the opposite category. It even says so right below the exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you ask about the *opposite category* $C^{op}$, *dual* to $C$.

Let $f^{op}\colon a\to b$ and $g^{op}\colon b\to c$ are morphisms of the category $C^{op}$(which correspond to morphisms $f\colon b\to a$ and $g\colon c\to b$ in $C$ ), then $g^{op}\circ f^{op}\colon=(f\circ g)^{op}$. Associativity of composition in $C^{op}$ implies from associativity of composition in $C$: 
$$(h^{op}\circ g^{op})\circ f^{op}=(g\circ h)^{op}\circ f^{op}=(f\circ(g\circ h))^{op}=((f\circ g)\circ h)^{op}=h^{op}\circ(f\circ g)^{op}=$$
$$=h^{op}\circ(g^{op}\circ f^{op})$$
The identity morphism of object $c\in Ob(C^{op})$ is $id_{C^{op}}(c):=id_C(c)^{op}$.

For more details, see [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/opposite+category)
or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_category).

Comment: So what you wrote about is exactly what the question asked? I am a bit in aw.

Comment: I wrote the definition of composition of morphisms in $C^{op}$, then proved it's associativity, and then indicated the identity morphisms of $C^{op}$. It's enough to say that $C^{op}$ is a category:)